# Access Couch DB database URL through rewritten URL, with query parameters

Tags: couchdb

I have my web site run out of a Couch DB instance, so I have my vhost configured to point to `/dbname/_design/app/_rewrite`.

I want to be able to access the index page from a web browser, while still accessing the Couch DB API over Ajax, so I set up a pair of rewrite rules in my `rewrites` field:

```
[ { "from": "/dbname/*", "to: ../../*" },
  { "from": "/*", "to: *" } ]
```

These rules work fine: I can access individual documents through a `/dbname/docname` URL, and I can point my web browser at the root of the site and access my attachments that way.

I'd now like to access the information on the database itself, in order to pass a `since` parameter to the `_changes` API.

1. `/dbname/` works fine
2. `/dbname/?name=value` doesn't redirect properly. In the Couch DB log, I see lines like `'GET' /dbname/_design/..?name=value 404`, whereas I'd expect to see `'GET' /dbname/?name=value 200`.

The second case is needed for Ajax from IE, where the `jquery.couch.js` code adds a fake query string to avoid caching.

How can I phrase my rewrite rules so that Couch DB rewrites `/dbname/?name=value` correctly?

**Edit:** To clarify, query strings work OK as long as there is something after the last / in the URL.

- `/dbname/docname?rev=xxx` works
- `/dbname/_changes?since=1` works
- `/dbname/?_=dummy` doesn't work; it rewrites to `/dbname/_design/..?_=dummy`

Comment: Sorry that I am not able to help. Most interesting how you are doing. I hope to follow your solution

Comment: Filed a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2031

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to duplicate your problem but it is working. Below is my interaction. (Note, I use the IP address, `127.0.0.1:5984`, to ensure no vhost/rewrite problems, then I access the "production" site via `localhost:5984`.

**There is a bug** it seems with query parameters being appended to rewrites ending with "..". Instead of rewriting to `../?key=val` it writes to `..?key=val` which CouchDB does not parse.

I do not think it is necessary to query a database URL with parameters. So one workaround is to always make sure you never do that. (E.g. if you blindly append no-op parameters to all queries to simplify the code, you'd have to alter that.)

Another workaround is to enable rewrite to the *root CouchDB URL*. This requires setting `/_config/httpd/secure_rewrites` to `false`.

```
{ "from":"/api/*", "to":"../../../*" }
```

Now you can query `http://localhost:5984/api/x?key=val` or `http://localhost:5984/api/x/_changes?since=5`. (You cannot query the root URL with parameters—it's still the bug, but in a less trafficked place.)

Following is the initial terminal session:

```
$ mkdir t
$ cd t
$ curl -XDELETE 127.0.0.1:5984/x 
{"ok":true}
$ curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:5984/x 
{"ok":true}
$ curl 127.0.0.1:5984
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.1"}

$ echo -n _design/test > _id
$ mkdir shows
$ echo 'function() { return "hello world!\n" }' > shows/hello.js
$ cat > rewrites.json
[ { "from":"/db/*", "to":"../../*" }
, { "from":"/*"   , "to":"*"}
]

$ echo '{}' > .couchapprc
$ couchapp push http://127.0.0.1:5984/x
$ curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_config/vhosts/localhost:5984 -d '"/x/_design/test/_rewrite"'
"/x/_design/test/_rewrite"

$ curl localhost:5984 # This is the design document.
{"_id":"_design/test","_rev":"1-e523efd669aa5375e711f8e4b764da7a","shows":{"hello":"function() { return \"hello world!\\n\" }"},"couchapp":{"signatures":{},"objects":{},"manifest":["rewrites.json","shows/","shows/hello.js"]},"rewrites":[{"to":"../../*","from":"/db/*"},{"to":"*","from":"/*"}]}
$ curl localhost:5984/_show/hello
hello world!

$ curl localhost:5984/db # This is the DB.
{"db_name":"x","doc_count":1,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":1,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":4185,"instance_start_time":"1298269455135987","disk_format_version":5,"committed_update_seq":1}
$ curl localhost:5984/db/_changes
{"results":[
{"seq":1,"id":"_design/test","changes":[{"rev":"1-e523efd669aa5375e711f8e4b764da7a"}]}
],
"last_seq":1}

$ curl localhost:5984/db/_changes?since=1 # Parameters accepted!
{"results":[

],
"last_seq":1}
```

Comment: Given the database above, what happens if you query `localhost:5984/db/?dummy=1`?

Comment: You are right. This looks like perhaps a rewriter bug. I will amend my answer with some workaround ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'll omit the query string where it causes a problem. It's being added by the Futon /_utils/script/jquery.couch.js script. When you're using IE, it adds a `?_=<timestamp>` parameter to all CouchDB calls, apparently to stop IE from caching the response. The place where it causes a problem is the `_changes` API, where jquery.couch.js first queries the `/dbname/` URL to obtain `update_seq`.

Comment: PS I might try hiding the database API behind some update and show functions, avoiding the need for the strange ../../ rewrite. However, it's not clear how I'd access the `_changes` API in this case. I can start a new SO question for this, though.