# couchdb public interface authentication through rewrites

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, couchdb

I have a website set on a specific domain which is completely separated from my couchdb url through rewrites and virtual hosts, and I got to a point where I need to add some user authentication using _sessions API but I'm afraid I can't do it with rewrites:

```
{
  "from": "auth",
  "to": "../../../_session"
}
```

gives me:

```
{"error":"insecure_rewrite_rule","reason":"too many ../.. segments"}
```

which is acceptable, but now I'm wondering how would I get the session authentication to work from my domain without exposing couchdb url, and also, the session seems to be related to the domain so if I login through couchdb.example.com it won't work when using mywebsite.com as the public interface?

Thanks

**PS.** I've just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059499/access-couch-db-database-url-through-rewritten-url-with-query-parameters/5062994#5062994) where there's an alternative by disabling `secure_rewrites` on the httpd config file, which seems to work, although, I was wondering that perhaps might be not a good approach and if is there something else which is ideal for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend to set `secure_rewrites=false` and don't worry about it.

We had a great discussion about [CouchDB rewrites and security](http://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/require_valid_user_error#reply_6336022) in the Iris Couch forum. Also see my post later about [using Audit CouchDB](http://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/require_valid_user_error#reply_6393897). These are the highlights:

- The `secure_rewrites` option is not the ultimate source of security for your data. At best, it is one layer in a multi-layer solution
- The ultimate source of security is the `_security` object in the database. So that is where you should focus your attention
- The [Audit CouchDB](http://github.com/iriscouch/audit_couchdb) tool scans every detail about your couch and it will tell you if any red-flags are present. It is implemented in Javascript so if you have NodeJS, you can run it; or simply reading the source code gives you an idea of what it is looking for.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot Jason, it feels really good to have such feedback. you're appreciated. I will definitely use it then, also, congratulations for audit_couchdb, I've just installed here and it is really useful. it will become part of my development process now. :) cheers

Comment: To set this through curl: curl -XPUT "$couch/_config/httpd/secure_rewrites" -d '"false"'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vhost, than `/_session` handler is available at the vhost root without any rewrite rules (by default).

See the section `[httpd]` of `default.ini`:

```
vhost_global_handlers = _utils, _uuids, _session, _oauth, _users
```